# Which of these is the sewer cleanout

Tags: plumbing, sewer, cleanout

I’m trying to locate the sewer cleanout. I found a box that looks like it contains it but there are 3 separate plugs. Which one should I use?

[image]

I also found this which I’m guessing is something else

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to do some experimenting. Remove the plugs and start running some water, flushing toilets, etc., and observe which way the water's running. If this is multi-family, there could be separate drains for each unit. If you have a building plan it might show up on it. There's not much else we can do from here.

Comment: It’s a single family home. Built 2018. I want to drain my pool. Could I use any of them? Do they all drain out to the same sewer system?

Comment: A: we don't have any way of knowing - you have to do more investigating to figure that out. B: you may need to drain your pool some other way, depending on local rules - ovewhelming the waste treatment plant with tens of thousands of gallons of water is not smiled upon and may result in a hefty fine. They may not mind, they may very much mind, you have to check locally. Sometimes you need a pool truck to pump out, or you need to pump to a storm drain, not a sanitary sewer, or you can send to the sewer but you have to schedule the release so it's at a point when they have capacity.

Comment: In Dallas pool drainage is often just pumped into the surface where it goes into the storm sewer and so into our local creek. This would surely be harmful to aquatic life in the creek, and I believe is against city regs. If I understand the rules, pool drainage and filter back flush is supposed to go into the sanitary sewer. I would think that the chlorine in the pool water would be consumed by reaction with organic matter in the sewer on it's way to the treatment plant.

Answer (score 3):

There are often two cleanouts close together on a single sewer line. These enter the underground line in a fitting which directs a probe one direction or the other on the line. At our house there is a double cleanout about 3 ft from the foundation. A probe in the outer one is directed under the slab and a probe in the  inner one is directed toward the street.